# calculate the average of a nested collection

Tags: php, laravel

I do have a collection and I want to do either one of the following: the sum or the average of a property in specific relation in that collection so for example I want to get the average from the `total` property in the following relation `orders.invoice`
so in the code I have to loop on all the orders (as the orders here are an array) and then go to each invoice (as the order here has one invoice) in each order and then calculate the average. so if we have 3 orders and those orders has an invoice with those values (in the `total` property) 50, 200 and 100, the return value will be `(50 + 200 + 100) / 3 = 116.7` if we are doing an average if we are doing sum it would be `50 + 200 + 100 = 350`

note that the collection could be nested and we don't know the type of the relation between the nested relations ex: "relation1.relation2.relatoin3" so if relation 1 is a collection we will need to loop on it and if relation2 is an object we just go directly to the next relation.

so far I have managed to do the sum but what's left is the average, here is the function:

```
 /**
 * calculate the sum/AVG based on the chosen property on a single relation or nested relations.
 * 
 * @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection | array $entity
 * @var string $path
 * @var string $property
 * @var 'sum'|'avg' $operation
 * @return float
 */
public static function compute($entity, string $path, string $property, string $operation = 'sum'): float
{
    $parts    = explode('.', $path, 2); // Limit to 2 parts
    $relation = $parts[0];
    $new_path = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : '';
    $result   = 0;
    $count    = 0;

    if (is_iterable($entity)) {
        $entity->each(function ($item) use (&$result, &$count, $path, $property, $operation) {
            $result += self::compute($item, $path, $property, $operation);
            $count++;
        });

        return $result;
    }
    
    if (is_iterable($entity->{$relation})) {
        collect($entity->{$relation})->each(function ($item) use (&$result, &$count, $new_path, $property, $operation) {
            if($new_path == '') {
                $result += $item->{$property};
                $count++;
            } else {
                $result += self::compute($item, $new_path, $property, $operation);
            }
        });
    } else if($entity->{$relation}) {
        if($new_path == '') {
            $result += $entity->{$relation}->{$property};
            $count++;
        } else {
            $result += self::compute($entity->{$relation}, $new_path, $property, $operation);
        }
    }

    if($operation == 'avg' && $count > 0) {
        // dd($count);
        $result /= 4; // here is the problem in the `avg` as we can't save the value of the $count on every function call as we do with $result 
    }

    return $result;
}
```

here is the test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Collection\NestedCollection;

class CollectionNestedComputationTest extends TestCase {
protected $data;

protected function setup(): void
{
    parent::setup();
    $this->data = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path('tests/Unit/data.json')))->results);
}

/**
 * single path.
 */
public function test_that_single_path_is_calculated_correctly(): void
{
    $path = 'devis';
    $property = 'id';

    $this->assertEquals(292763, NestedCollection::compute($this->data, $path, $property, 'sum'));
    $this->assertEquals(73190.75, NestedCollection::compute($this->data, $path, $property, 'avg'));
}

/**
 * nested path.
 */
public function test_that_nested_path_is_calculated_correctly(): void
{
    $path = 'devis.data.trajets.brands';
    $property = '1';

    $this->assertEquals(1940, NestedCollection::compute($this->data, $path, $property, 'sum'));
    $this->assertEquals(485, NestedCollection::compute($this->data, $path, $property, 'avg'));
}
```

}

and here is the data used in the test:

```
{
"results": [
{
    "id": 10575,
    "devis": {
        "id": 73258,
        "data": {
            "trajets": [
                {
                    "brands": {
                        "1": -990
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 10574,
    "devis": {
        "id": 73235,
        "data": {
            "trajets": [
                {
                    "brands": {
                        "1": "990"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 10573,
    "devis": {
        "id": 73143,
        "data": {
            "trajets": [
                {
                    "brands": {
                        "1": "1250"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 10572,
    "devis": {
        "id": 73127,
        "data": {
            "trajets": [
                {
                    "brands": {
                        "1": "690"
                    }
                }
            ]
         }
    }
}
]
```

}

as I mentioned above the sum works as excepted but the average is not working as expected

Comment: You would need to get a total of all the values right, and a count of how many orders you encountered.
So create an initial variable of `$total` or something and keep adding every amount you encounter to it.
Create an initial variable `$amountOfOrders` and increment it every loop.
After the loop you can do `$average = $total / $amountOfOrders;` right?

Comment: @geertjanknapen that's what I'm doing here, the problem is not about the format the problem is that the $count is not being incremented in every loop